# What data should be held in the Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux

currently working on learning React and Redux. Now my question is what content I should be storing in my Redux Data Tree?

For example, there will be three different pages:

- Contacts
- Posts
- Comments

Now for each of the pages above they will be pulling the necessary data from the database. Am I suppose to load in all of the data at once, and keep it all in the store (even if it is on a separate page)? Or am I suppose to load in just the necessary pieces of data for that specific page in to the store, and still keep the other fields in the store, but make them empty?

Comment: My vote is for the second option.There is no need to load all the data at once. If the user never hits that page, then there is no reason to add that much more to the application. Only fetch the data when needed and then when the data comes back, update the store accordingly

Comment: Hello, so should I add blanks to my tree like the following `contants: []` or should I just not even add the `contacts` to my tree until they are needed?

Comment: Typically all your reducers will initialize with initial state on page load, which would include an empty contacts array in your example. Technically in redux you return from your reducer whatever you want, but if you switch pages from posts to contacts and you haven't initialized an empty contacts array you might get a null crash in your component (unless you check for null there). Better to setup default states for your whole app as it's not expensive to do so, and it makes it clear to a reader of your code what data you're expecting to arrive.

Comment: Ok thank you! Makes perfect sense